# Bootstrap modal not appearing to edit table element Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I have a patients model with various fields displayed in a table with an edit and destroy button on each row. I want the edit button to open up a bootstrap modal to edit that particular patient. I have a _form.html.erb partial for this purpose. When I load the page the all the partials are rendered: "Rendered patients/_form.html.erb". When I press any of the edit buttons the modal does not appear.

This is my patients/index.html.erb

```
<div class="media">
<div class="media-body">
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>DOB</th>
      <th>Number</th>
      <th>Address 1</th>
      <th>Address 2</th>
      <th>Address 3</th>
      <th>Address 4</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class ="patientsTable">
    <% @patients.each do |patient| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= patient.name %></td>
        <td><%= patient.surname %></td>
        <td><%= patient.email %></td>
        <td><%= patient.date %></td>
        <td><%= patient.number %></td>
        <td><%= patient.address1 %></td>
        <td><%= patient.address2 %></td>
        <td><%= patient.address3 %></td>
        <td><%= patient.address4 %></td>

        <td><%= link_to 'Chart', href="/landingpage/xrays" %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit',  '#', 'data-target' => "#myModal_#{patient.id}", 'data-toggle' => 'modal'  %>
      <div class="modal fade" id='<%= "myModal_#{patient.id}" %>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <%= render 'patients/form', patient: patient %>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', patient, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>

      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>



<h4>Add Patient</h4>

<%= form_for Patient.new do |f| %>
  <label>Name</label>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <label>Surname</label>
  <%= f.text_field :surname %>

  <label>Email</label>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>

  <label>DOB</label>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>

  <label>Number</label>
  <%= f.text_field :number %>

  <label>Address 1</label>
  <%= f.text_field :address1 %>

  <label>Address 2</label>
  <%= f.text_field :address2 %>

  <label>Address 3</label>
  <%= f.text_field :address3 %>

  <label>Address 4</label>
  <%= f.text_field :address4 %>

  <%=f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

This is my PatientsController

```
class PatientsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @patients = Patient.all
    @patient = Patient.new
end

def show 
end

def new
    @patient = Patient.new
end

def edit
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
end
def destroy
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:id])
    @patient.destroy
    redirect_to patients_path
end
def create
    @patient = Patient.create(patient_params)
    @patient.save
    redirect_to patients_path
end

def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @patient.update(patient_params)

    format.js {}
  else
    format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    format.json { render json: @patient.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
 end
end


private
    def patient_params
        params.require(:patient).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :date, :number, :address1, :address2, :address3, :address4)
    end
end
```

This is my patients/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(patient, remote: true) do |f| %>
<% if @patient.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@patient.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% @patient.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>

<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :surname %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :surname %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :email %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :date %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :number %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :number %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address1 %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :address1 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address2 %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :address2 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address3 %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :address3 %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :address4 %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :address4 %>
</div>

<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
```

I cannot figure out why the modal is not appearing. If you can spot why I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <div class="modal fade show" id='<%= "myModal_#{patient.id}" %>' tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        .
        .
        .
        .
        .
      </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

add a class **show**  along with modal and fade. if that doesnt seems to work add class **in** insted

Comment: Adding the **in** class worked. Really appreciate that!

Comment: would you have any idea why the close buttons or save changes button is not closing the modal?

Comment: Add this data attribute to your button `data-dismiss="modal"`

for example 

`<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" >close</button>`